# android get last active intent before screen lock

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

I have been creating a secure data android application, therefore i dont want my application to be viewed without login through a valid password.

So i need to land on login page, in case, phone is locked, some other application viewed,etc. I have achieved this using http://www.mediafire.com/download/mb6o7mtbg1cucx9/AlwaysLogin.zip.

Now i need that after login, the application resumes the same activity which was last loaded.

Currently, the main menu is loaded after login button click.

Comment: What did you tey already?

Comment: i solved the problem by keeping a global variable and assigning it the class name on activity load,